# What is happening when I change directory and then run Python?

Tags: python

I have looked at so many posts, and I am still struggling to grasp this.

testfile.txt is in the /home/myusername folder

```
$ pwd
/home/myusername

$ python3

>>> open('testfile.txt')
#Success

>>> quit()

$ cd folderA
$ python3
>>> open('testfile.txt')
#No such file

// Move testfile to folderA
>>> open('testfile.txt')
#No such file

Try to change directory,
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir("folderA")
>>> open('testfile.txt')
#fail, no such file
```

So, I'm just wondering what's going on here... 
1) When I change directory the Python interpreter seems to not find my file in the directory I changed to OR even in the home/username directory where it was working before I changed directory!!
2) If I use os to change directory to a folder this seems to do nothing for me.

So, if my steps are correct, changing directory in terminal and then running python seems to upset where python's relative path is.. and os.chdir doesn't seem to help.

FYI: I am running Ubuntu (Windows) from Command Prompt, and even when I try absolute path '/home/username/folder/file.txt' it still isn't working. This is the best I can do... Please help!

Comment: I'm sorry, but my honnest guess is that you failed moving the file to folderA. Can you give more details as to how you moved it?

Comment: This *should* work. Chances are something else is going wrong (e.g. a typo when you move the file)

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -l` in folderA

Comment: Yeah, chances are `// Move testfile to folderA` is not actually moving the testfile to folderA

Comment: The problem was that I made the text files in Windows, just by right-clicking, and clearly (obviously?) this didn't update the directory information in Ubuntu. If I make the file within Linux then it can be opened with Python as expected.